# How to print username as path in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to give every registered user a unique url shown on their user page which they can copy and paste...promoting their page.
I had this working using Pages and Tokens...but now I've ditched Panels/Pages for a custom user-profile.tpl.php
I've tried this:

print ($user->name);

But this returns the user name as Hillay Swag instead of hillary-swag

How can I print the url version of the user name instead of the human version?

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = drupal_get_path_alias('user/' . $user->uid);
print $link;
```

That will print out `users/admin`. Further, if you only want the username part of the path (no `users/`) you could cut it with PHP's `substr()` function.